# Cartesian product of undefined length Matlab

Tags: matlab, cartesian-product

There is a downloadable function called CARTPROD which gives the cartesian product of given vectors
([link to CARTPROD function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5475-cartprod--cartesian-product-of-multiple-sets?focused=5058922&tab=fun))

For example

```
cartprod(1:3,1:3)

ans =
 1     1
 2     1
 3     1
 1     2
 2     2
 3     2
 1     3
 2     3
 3     3
```

However, is there a way in which I can specify how many times a given vector should be read in the cartesian product. I want something like this:

```
%If user chooses the vector to be used 4 times
cartprod(1:3,1:3,1:3, 1:3)

%If user chooses the vector to be used 2 times
cartprod(1:3,1:3)
```

I have tried thinking about it, but I can't think of doing it any way besides manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [comma separated lists](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). Haven't tested this, but try

```
myvec={1:3,1:3,1:3,1:3}; 
cartprod(myvec{:}); %get cartprod of all vectors in the cell-array.
```

or as @Sardar_Usama pointed out, you can replace `myvec={1:3,1:3,1:3,1:3}` with this:

```
n=4; %number of repeated vectors
myvec=repmat({1:3},1,n); %repeat cell-array {1:3} 4 times
```

Comment: You need to automate the first line instead of manually entering `1:3` multiple times. i.e. by something like this: `myvec=repmat({1:3},n,1)`

Comment: This seems to work great! Thanks so much Sardar and  user2305193

Answer (score 1):

The other answer points out how you can use the same [`cartprod`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5475-cartprod--cartesian-product-of-multiple-sets) function from the FEX. However, there is another function named [`combvec`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/combvec.html) (from the Neural Network Toolbox) which does exactly the same.

```
n = 4;  %Number of times to be repeated
myvec = repmat({1:3},1,n);    %Repeating the cell array vector
result = combvec(myvec{:}).'; %Converting to comma-separated list and applying combvec
```